# QT6 and QTCharts, include in Visual Studio doesn't work?

Tags: c++, qt, qtcharts

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 and installed the QT version 6.2.2. In installer options I've choosen only msvc2019_64 and QTCharts. All project desing worked well until I wanted to work with charts. In the header file I have:

```
#include <QtCharts>
#pragma comment(lib, "QtCharts")
using namespace QtCharts;
```

"Using namespace" statement is underscored and says "name must be a namespace name"
In project properties I have:

- in C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories -> "C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtCharts"
- same in  Additional #using Directories
- in Linker -> Input -> "C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\lib\Qt6Charts.lib" and "C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\lib\Qt6Chartsd.lib"
- I've copied "C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\bin\Qt6Charts.dll" and "C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\bin\Qt6Chartsd.dll" into the main project folder.
- I've added to the project existing header files "qtcharts-config.h", "qchart.h"

Anybody did it before and knows how to solve it?

Comment: QtCharts (and all other Qt modules also) don't use a namespace with it's prefix anywhere. 
Use a proper build system like qmake or cmake to create the solution file - otherwise you will have to call moc and others by yourself. Or use the Qt VS Plugin.

Comment: @chehrlic according to the documentation I'm doing it at least partially correct: [link](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-index.html). I've installed QT VS Plugin, sure. I never used qmake or cmake. However i deleted now using namespace, pragma comment and header files, now it runs lol.